# Apache Qpid JMS client message producer getting stuck and not delivering to queue

Tags: jms, amqp, qpid

I am trying to send a message to the Qpid broker over the AMQP 1.0 protocol. The queue is named `queue2` and it is already created under default virtualhost. However, `producer.send(message)` is getting stuck forever. The same code is working for connecting to Azure Service Bus. I'm using qpid-jms-client 0.58. Producer code is:

```java
Hashtable<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<>();
hashtable.put("connectionfactory.myFactoryLookup", protocol + "://" + url + "?amqp.idleTimeout=120000&amqp.traceFrames=true");
hashtable.put("queue.myQueueLookup", queueName);
hashtable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.qpid.jms.jndi.JmsInitialContextFactory");

Context context = new InitialContext(hashtable);

ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("myFactoryLookup");
queue = (Destination) context.lookup("myQueueLookup");

Connection connection = factory.createConnection(username, password);
connection.setExceptionListener(new AmqpConnectionFactory.MyExceptionListener());

connection.start();

Session session=connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// session.createQueue("queue3");
Queue queue = new JmsQueue("queue2");
MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage("new message");
messageProducer.send(textMessage)
```

I can see Connection and session is successfully established on Qpid broker dashboard:
[image: Qpid Broker dashboard]

Thread dump for application at time of producing

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x000000078327c550> (a org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProgressiveProviderFuture)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProgressiveProviderFuture.sync(ProgressiveProviderFuture.java:154)
    - locked <0x000000078327c550> (a org.apache.qpid.jms.provider.ProgressiveProviderFuture)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsConnection.send(JmsConnection.java:773)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsNoTxTransactionContext.send(JmsNoTxTransactionContext.java:37)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.send(JmsSession.java:964)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.send(JmsSession.java:843)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsMessageProducer.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducer.java:252)
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsMessageProducer.send(JmsMessageProducer.java:182)
```

I have tried to run [this example](https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/tree/0.58.0/qpid-jms-examples) which gave the same result.

Comment: @JustinBertram I think the problem may be how I have configured Qpid broker J. As with service bus same code works fine. I have tried to run https://github.com/apache/qpid-jms/tree/0.58.0/qpid-jms-examples , which also put me on same situation. Update thread dump for application on question. I don't see any log on thread dump on qpid broker J at time of ``` producer.send```

Answer (score 1):

In general if the client is not sending it is because the remote has not granted it credit to do so.  You can debug the client state using the [protocol trace](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-jms-1.1.0/docs/index.html#tracing) feature (just set PN_TRACE_FRM=true and run the client).

Likely you have misconfigured the Broker-J somehow and the destination you've created doesn't allow any messages to be sent or you've sent enough that you've tripped the write limit.  You should consult the [configuration](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-8.0.6/book/Java-Broker-Concepts-Queues.html#Java-Broker-Concepts-Queue-OverflowPolicy) guide and review what you've already setup.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Finally got the issue. **Filesystem is over 90 per cent full, enforcing flow control.** So deleted files from my machine and it started working.
https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-broker-j-7.0.7/book/Java-Broker-Runtime-Disk-Space-Management.html